# how to test method with try-with-resources

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

how can I unit test a method which uses try-with-resources?

As it uses new operator in try clause I cannot mock it. I don't want to use PowerMock. It seems like the only way is to create integration test?

```
public void methodToBeTested(File file) {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        //some logic I want to test which uses fis object
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //print stacktrace
    }
}
```

Comment: Illustrate your question with a concrete code please.

Comment: You could move the dependency instantiation into a *factory class* and pass that as *constructor parameter* to your code under test. The factory class itself would be *too simple to fail* and therfore not needed to be tested.

Comment: @davidxxx sample code inserted

Comment: @TimothyTruckle do you propose to do something like:
*try (FileInputStream fis = getCreatedFromFactory(file))*
??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the dependency instantiation into a *factory* class and pass that as *constructor parameter* to your code under test. The factory class itself would be *too simple to fail* and therfore not needed to be tested.

> do you propose to do something like:
>
> ```
> try (FileInputStream fis = getCreatedFromFactory(file)) ??
> ```
>
> – JavaIntern

Almost...

```
@Singleton
public class InputStreamFactory { // too simple to fail -> no UnitTests
   public InputStream createFor(File file) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
       retrun new FileInputStream(file);
   }
}
```

---

```
class UnitUnderTest {
   private final InputStreamFactory inputStreamFactory;
   UnitUnderTest(@Inject InputStreamFactory inputStreamFactory){
      this.inputStreamFactory=inputStreamFactory;
   }

   public void methodToBeTested(File file) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = inputStreamFactory.createFor(file)) {
            //some logic I want to test which uses fis object
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //print stacktrace
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class UnitUnderTestTest{
   @Rule
   public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

   @Mock
   private InputStreamFactory inputStreamFactory;

   @Mock
   private InputStream inputStream;

   private final File inputFile = new File("whatever");

    // no init here, mock for inputStream not yet created
   private UnitUnderTest unitUnderTest;
   /* I don't use @InjectMocks
      since it does not cause compile error
      if constructor misses parameter */

   @Before
   public void setup() {
       unitUnderTest = new UnitUnderTest(inputStreamFactory);
       doReturn(inputStream).when(inputStreamFactory).createFor(any(File.class);
   }

   @Test
   public void createsInputStreamFromFilePassed() {
       // arrange
       /* nothing to do */

       // act
       new UnitUnderTest(inputStreamFactory).methodToBeTested(inputFile);

       // assert
       verify(inputStreamFactory).createFor(inputFile); 
       verify(inputStream).close(); 
   }
}
```